# How to join Windows 10 Mobile to a domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-10, direct-access

We are currently experimenting with Microsoft Lumia 950 running Windows 10 Mobile and Microsoft's Display Dock.

Now I am wondering how I can join this mobile device to the existing lab Domain. Thanks for any pointers. Does Win10 Mobile Support `Direct Access`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows Mobile does not support Active Directory. However, you can manage Windows Mobile devices with SCCM or [Intune](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2015/02/01/manage-mobile-devices.aspx), both of which are AD aware.

An alternative is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16710174/windows-phone-8-and-active-directory-authentication): using Azure Active Directory to host AD roles.

Comment: Azure ad is the way to go here with INTUNE managing the device.. Currently Windows 10 on a phone cannot join an adds domain

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Mobile doesn't support DirectAccess and can not be join as a computer in Active Directory.

However, you can use Device Registration in Active Directory or Azure Active Directory. Device Registration can be use to force MDM Enrollment and conditionnal Access with Exchange or Sharepoint Online for exemple.

Regards

Stanislas

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Windows 10 mobile has a Domain join feature yet, currently Windows Continuum is in beginning stage and longways to go to get all features like normal desktop OS, need a enterprise windows 10 mobile OS to have Domain join function, MS not released enterprise windows 10 mobile OS

Workplace Join can be used and it's a windows server 2012 R2 feature